# How can I connect the WASD-keys to specific events?

Tags: java

I am pretty new to programming, but I am curios and want to learn more. Currently, I’m trying to make a very simple program where I can move a 2-dimenstional ball around on the screen. However, currently I have to use buttons in the program to move the ball. I would like to be able to use the WASD or such. I have searched through this site, but haven’t found something that’s basic enough.
My question is actually quite simple – how can I make it so when I press a key, for example W, the ball moves in that direction (or whatever event I add to it)? I saw something about like this on this site: 
        ( g.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)

However, the above described code doesn’t work to make the ball move. Is there any simple code to connect a pressed key and an event? Notice that I use NetBeans.

Below, you can see a description of what I’m trying to work with (and which doesn’t work):

EDIT:
To clerify, here is the whole code I'm working with, as an example:

```
    package gamePanel;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    public class GamePanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {


public GamePanel() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    btnUp = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnDown = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnLeft = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnRight = new javax.swing.JButton();

    btnUp.setText("Up");
    btnUp.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnUpActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnDown.setText("Down");
    btnDown.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnDownActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnLeft.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(140, 140, 140));
    btnLeft.setText("Left");
    btnLeft.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnLeftActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnRight.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(140, 140, 140));
    btnRight.setText("Right");
    btnRight.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnRightActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(84, 84, 84)
            .addComponent(btnLeft, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(btnUp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnDown, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(btnRight)
            .addContainerGap(129, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(238, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnUp)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnDown)
                .addComponent(btnLeft)
                .addComponent(btnRight))
            .addGap(10, 10, 10))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

private void btnUpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    y -= 10;
    repaint();
}                                     

private void btnDownActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    y += 10;
    repaint();
}                                       

private void btnLeftActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    x -= 10;
    repaint();
}                                       

private void btnRightActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    x += 10;
    repaint();
}                                        

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 25, 25);
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnDown;
private javax.swing.JButton btnLeft;
private javax.swing.JButton btnRight;
private javax.swing.JButton btnUp;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: try with `KeyListener`

Comment: What is `g`? And which method contains the mentioned code?

Comment: `KeyListener`.. There are a plethora of tutorials and examples from  "He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named" (A.K.A. Google)

Comment: The method that contains this is:
        private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Key Bindings.  Here's a method from one of my Swing applications.  I tied the keys to a JPanel (gridPanel), but you can tie them to any Swing component you want.

```
private void setKeyBindings() {
    InputMap inputMap = 
            gridPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "up arrow");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "down arrow");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "left arrow");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "right arrow");

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "up arrow");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "down arrow");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "left arrow");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "right arrow");

    inputMap = gridPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_FOCUSED);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "up arrow");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "down arrow");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "left arrow");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "right arrow");


    gridPanel.getActionMap().put("up arrow", 
            new UpArrowAction(this, model));
    gridPanel.getActionMap().put("down arrow", 
            new DownArrowAction(this, model));
    gridPanel.getActionMap().put("left arrow", 
            new LeftArrowAction(this, model));
    gridPanel.getActionMap().put("right arrow", 
            new RightArrowAction(this, model));
}
```

The whole Java Swing application can be found in my [2048 Game in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=516) article.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said in the comments, you could use a `KeyListener` (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) for more details) type [event listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) like so:

```
myJPanel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override 
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            myBall.y -= 10;
            myJPanel.repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            myBall.y += 10;
            myJPanel.repaint();
        }
        ...
    }
});
```

The above example assumes that you have already created a `JPanel` object (`myJPanel`), which you have added/will be adding to your overall graphics context (an instance of `JFrame`, for example). It also makes the assumption that `myJPanel` is your main canvas object, *i.e.* that you'll be adding (and drawing) your `myBall` object onto THAT particular canvas.

Try to figure out the rest of the arrow key mappings (right, left etc.) yourself (*Hint: follow the given pattern!*).

PS.: Also note that to have your ball actually drawn out (and updated) on the canvas, you'll need to specify the expected behaviour of `myJPanel.repaint()` (the method we used in the previous code snippet). To achieve this, you'll need override the `JPanel#paintComponent(..)` method when defining your `myJPanel` canvas, *e.g.* something like the following:

```
JPanel myJPanel = new JPanel() {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.repaint(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2D.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2D.fill(myBall);
    }
}
```

which in turn assumes that your `myBall` has been created using the `Ellipse2D` class (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html)) included in the [Java 2D API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/). For example:

```
Ellipse2D.Double myBall = new Ellipse2D.Double(100, 100, 10, 10);
```

Boy, did this post turn out long :) however it should contain all the necessary information to get your basic simulation working. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. :) Hopefully I will be able to learn something from this.